# Sinusoidal expression: how to find amplitude and phase

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like to know the general proceeding to find A and $\phi$ if the sinusoidal expression is

$$y=A \sin(wt-\phi)$$

Many thanks

Comment: You might want to look at some examples with http://www.wolframalpha.com/. Is this the original problem or are their extra constraints?

Comment: Are we to assume that you are given $y$, $\omega$, and $t$?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 omega yes, t is the indipendent variable and y is the dipendent variable..

Comment: How many values of $t$ do you have and what are they? Can you create a vector of $y$ from arbitrary values of $t$?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have three unknowns, namely "A", "Omega" and "Phi", you need at least three different values of "y" corresponding to three values of "t". Then, you see that you have 3 equations for three unknowns which simplify to 2 just because "A" is a multiplier; the ratoing the results will help.

If you have more than three data points (containing by definition some noise in the data), then the problem has to be treated as non linear regression. I do not think that this is your problem.